# How to click a link using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link:

```
<a href="#panel2-2">Manage Lists</a>
```

I want to "click" this link using jquery or javascript. I've tried:

```
$("#panel2-2").click(function(){}); 
$("#panel2-2").trigger('click');
```

It doesn't work! How can I do a click like this using javascript?

Comment: Okay seriously? What is with the downvotes? It's a totally legitimate question?

Comment: Probably the lack of research effort you've shown - if you had done even the simplest debugging on this you would have found out the problem is not with `click()` or `trigger()`, but that `$("#panel2-2")` doesn't get you the object you're expecting. That would have led you to fix the code, or at least ask the right question.

Comment: That's a really big assumption to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

For your case, you would use something like this:

```
$( "a[href='#panel2-2']" ).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need

```
$('[href="#panel2-2"]').trigger('click');
```

or

```
$('[href="#panel2-2"]').click();
```